# Express js session-- Create only for logged in users

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I'm using express-session Node module for secure session cookies.

```
// Secure session cookie that ensures certain requests require an active session
app.use(expressSession({
    secret: "wouldn'tyouliketoknow", 
    cookie: {
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600), // 1 hour
        httpOnly: true, 
        secure: true, // Requires https connection
    }, 
    // Stores sessions in Mongo DB
    store: new MongoStore({
        host: mongo, 
        port: 27017, 
        db: 'iod', 
        collection: 'sessions'
    }),
    // Gets rid of the annoying deprecated messages
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

This creates a secure session cookie no matter what the request is. I only wanna create a session only for when a user successfully logs in, e.g. a request like this:

```
app.get("/authenticate/:username/:password", function(req, res, next) {
    ...
});
```

Basically I want the cookie created only when a condition is successfully met within the get handler.

How would I go about doing that? Appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So express will run middleware in the order you add it to the `app`. So the normal strategy here to achieve your goal would be to make sure you define:

1. All static and non-session routes (images, fonts, css, marketing pages, etc)
2. The session middleware
3. All application routes. You can't just have this on your login route because you'll need to enforce a logged-in user on all application routes requiring both a session as well as an authenticated user.

But specifically to answer you question even though this approach is not ultimately viable, you would just convert your session from a global middleware to a middleware added just to that one route:

```
var sessionMW = expressSession({
    secret: "wouldn'tyouliketoknow", 
    cookie: {
        maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600), // 1 hour
        httpOnly: true, 
        secure: true, // Requires https connection
    }, 
    // Stores sessions in Mongo DB
    store: new MongoStore({
        host: mongo, 
        port: 27017, 
        db: 'iod', 
        collection: 'sessions'
    }),
    // Gets rid of the annoying deprecated messages
    resave: false, 
    saveUninitialized: false
});
app.get("/authenticate/:username/:password", sessionMW, function(req, res, next) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the approach I had is not ultimately viable or the one you have coded? I have no problem with any approach as long as it works.

Comment: As for #3, I only want cookie creation on that route. True other routes would use cookies, but they would only read cookies and not create them.

Comment: I've only seen apps that either just A) use the session middleware everywhere or B) use the session middleware on all "app" routes and omit it for "static" routes. I haven't seen it only used on a single route so I'm not sure that's going to play out for you. But in any case, make sure the other routes in your app redirect to your login page if a request arrives with no session.

Comment: If a request arrives with no session how do I prevent one from being created? Sorry if that sounds dumb I'm pretty new to Express.

Comment: As long as a request does NOT get routed through the session middleware, no session will be created. So if it's a request for a static file, for example, and the static middleware responds and does not call `next` (thus ending the middleware chain), no session will be created.